# iptables, limit openvpn forwarding for specific destination sub-nets

Tags: openvpn, iptables

I'm attempting to setup a openvpn server, which runs 2 different instances of openvpn, to provide access to different vpc subnets.

If users are connected to the 10.6.0.0/24, they should have access only to certain subnets, but if they're connected to 10.7.0.0/24, they should have access to all VPC subnets.

To attempt to achieve this, I've written the following iptables commands...

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.6.0.0/24 -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.7.0.0/24 -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.121.0.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.111.0.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.7.0.0/24 -d 10.120.0.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.7.0.0/24 -d 10.110.0.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD REJECT
```

Subnets 10.121.0.0/18 and 10.111.0.0/18 are intended to be accessible by any vpn user, but 10.120.0.0/18 and 10.110.0.0/18 should only be accessible to 10.7.0.0/24 users.

This seems logical to me, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Users on 10.6.0.0/24 are still able to ping servers in 10.120.0.0/18 and 10.110.0.0/18

I'm hoping someone might be able to point out what I'm doing wrong. Clearly my understanding of iptables is incorrect.

I've found a solution to part of my problem.

It seems that it didn't like REJECT. When I tried to run this manually from the command line, it gives the error...

```
iptables: Bad policy name. Run `dmesg' for more information.
```

I changed it to the following...

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

The problem is that now it simply drops all FORWARD requests. It seems to ignore all the other rules.

Comment: What are your _other_ rules in the 'FORWARD' chain?

Comment: These are all the rules I'm adding manually, but maybe there are others that something else is adding. I'll check, and update the question.